# What does it mean to say that a forcing "collapses cardinals"?

Tags: set-theory, terminology, forcing

I hear the following terminology a lot: "So-and-so forcing collapses cardinals." Does this just mean that certain cardinals in the ground model are no longer cardinals in the forcing extension?

If not, what does it mean?

Comment: Yes, that's the meaning.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I thought it meant that a cardinal will have lower cardinality in the extension.

Comment: @MattN. Saying "has lower cardinality" is somewhat inexact. What it means is that the $\aleph_\beta$ of the ground model has become the $\aleph_\alpha$ in the generic extension (where $\alpha < \beta$).  In order for this to happen, some of of the cardinals in the ground model are no longer cardinals in the extension.

Comment: @Arthur: I always found it to have some sort of a multiple meaning when applied to a particular cardinal, "$\kappa$ is collapsed to be $\aleph_1$" or "$\aleph_1$ is collapsed". But of course, in either case the forcing collapses cardinals.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Yes, that's what I meant. Thank you for your comment. : ) But I'm still confused how this implies that some cardinals are no longer cardinals in the extension.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yeah, I should probably heavily edit my comment. (Good thing I still can!) I'm sort of trying to produce something consistent with both interpretations, but am failing badly right now.

Comment: @ArthurFischer, you write: "It means that $\aleph_\beta$ of the ground model has become $\aleph_\alpha$ in the generic extension (where $\alpha<\beta$)." Isn't it more like: "The ordinal that is $\aleph_\beta$ in the ground model is no longer $\aleph_\beta$ in the generic extension"? There's no reason that $\aleph_\beta$ should automatically end up as a new aleph number.

Comment: @MattN.: As Asaf says, there are two senses in which cardinal collapsing can be said to have occurred. In the first, you explicitly add a surjection $\omega_\alpha^M \to \omega_\beta^M$, in which case $\omega_\beta^M$ clearly ceases to be a cardinal in the extension. Another way is more akin to the [Levy collapse](http://planetmath.org/levycollapse) where we ensure that $\omega_\beta^M$ becomes $\omega_{\alpha}$ by destroying the "cardinal-ness" of $\omega_\delta^M$ for each $\alpha \leq \delta < \beta$. (This second is what I was thinking in my previous comment.)

Comment: @user18921: Yeah, what you wrote is much better. I think I'll slink away in embarrassment now. ;-)

Comment: @Arthur: Someone, at some point, will have to write an answer. You can still redeem yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A forcing collapses cardinals iff (by definition) some cardinal of the ground model is no longer a cardinal in the forcing extension.

Naturally, this means that there is some $\kappa$ in the ground model whose cardinality in the extension is strictly smaller than $\kappa$ (e.g., let $\kappa$ be the first cardinal that witnesses the definition above). Note that there may still be ordinals $\beta$ such that the $\aleph_\beta$ of the ground model is the $\aleph_\beta$ of the extension, even if some cardinals strictly smaller than $\aleph_\beta$ have been collapsed. For example, suppose that the $\aleph_1$ of the ground model is no longer a cardinal, while cardinals larger than $\aleph_1$ are preserved (this is achieved via the forcing usually denoted $\mathrm{Col}(\omega,\aleph_1)$). This means that the $\aleph_1$ of the ground model is a countable ordinal in the extension. Since the $\aleph_2$ of the ground model is still a cardinal, it must now be the $\aleph_1$ of the extension. Similarly, $\aleph_3$ becomes $\aleph_2$, etc, but $\aleph_\omega$ stays $\aleph_\omega$ and, for any $\beta\ge\omega$, $\aleph_\beta$ stays $\aleph_\beta$. Note that this applies to $\aleph_{\omega_1^V}$, even though $\omega_1^V$ is no longer a cardinal. In this case, $\aleph_{\omega_1^V}$ is now a cardinal of cofinality $\omega$, and $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ is a larger cardinal, simply because $\omega_1=\omega_2^V>\omega_1^V$.

That said, just because a forcing is a collapse forcing, it does not mean that cardinals are collapsed when it is applied. For example, $\mathrm{Col}(\omega,\omega)$ is just Cohen forcing, which does not collapse any cardinals. Another example is $\mathrm{Col}(\omega,<\omega_1)$. In choiceless contexts, the notation is used sometimes even if some non-well-ordered cardinals are involved.  A word of caution is also in order: To say that a forcing collapses a cardinal $\kappa$ does not quite mean that $\kappa$ is no longer a cardinal in the extension. For instance, it may be that $\kappa$ is now a *smaller* cardinal than it was originally.

Comment: Andres, perhaps you can add a bit on the seemingly interchangeable terminology "$\kappa$ is collapsed" to mean either that $\kappa$ is no longer a cardinal, or that it is a smaller cardinal.

Comment: Sure, why not?${}$

Comment: I could think of any number of reasons. For example, I'm going to take a nap right now. That would be an excellent reason to postpone the editing for later. ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I love naps and I recommend them to people constantly. Just sayin'.

Comment: Too late.${}{}{}$

Comment: So would it be fair to say that $\kappa$ is collapsed iff $|\kappa|_{V[G]} < \kappa,$ where $<$ is the natural order on the ordinal numbers?

Comment: @user18921 I do not currently see why not. I would probably be even more explicit, saying something along the lines of "$\kappa$ is collapsed to size $\eta$", or "$\kappa=\aleph_\alpha$ is collapsed to be now $\aleph_\gamma$", or words to that effect that clarify the change that has taken place.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, thanks.

Comment: @user18921 Glad I could help.

Comment: @user18921: If you constantly recommend people to nap, when do you have time to take a nap yourself? If you recommend people to take a constant nap, doesn't that mean you recommend them to die? In either case, the result is disturbing. ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, think of me like a function. Just because the subset of my codomain (consisting of all possible recommendations I can make) corresponding to my range is $\{\mbox{"nap"}\},$ that doesn't mean that my domain (consisting of all states I can be in) equals the singleton $\{\mbox{"napping"}\}.$

Comment: He he, not sure that makes any sense.